# FPGA Timing Constrain Problem

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga, fifo

I am using the `Cyclone V` `DE1-SoC` in transferring data between `HPS` and `FPGA`, using 2 `FIFO`. I am facing a problem of very late data arriving time, causing the `slack` to be very negative.

```
...
if ((Processing_state == 4'd5) && (FPGA_to_HPS_state == 0))
    begin
        a <= a + memo[i] * memo[i];
        Processing_state <= 4'd4 ;
    end    
    
if (Processing_state == 4)
    begin
        
        if (|a == 0)
        begin
            k<=a;
            Processing_state <= 4'd0 ;
        end
        
        else if (|a != 0)
        begin
            
            if(j == 20479)
            begin
                b <= a >> 12 ;
                Processing_state <= 4'd4; //signal fpga the data is ready to be sent
            end
            
            else
            begin
                j <= j + 1;
                Processing_state <= 4'd0 ;
            end
        end
    end
    
    if (Processing_state == 4)
    begin
        Processing_state <= 3;    
        data_buffer_valid <= 1'b1 ;
        c <= b;
        
    end
    
    if (Processing_state == 3)
    begin
        Processing_state <= 2;    
        mean <= c / 5;
    end
    
    if (Processing_state == 2)
    begin
        Processing_state <= 1;
        meaninput <= mean;
    end
    
    if (Processing_state == 4'd1)
    begin
        Processing_state <= 4'd0 ; 
        data_buffer_valid <= 1'b1 ;
        a <= 0;
        j <= 0;
        
    end
...

if ((FPGA_to_HPS_state==0) && (!(fpga_to_hps_in_csr_readdata[0])) && data_buffer_valid)
    begin
        fpga_to_hps_in_writedata <= meaninput;
        fpga_to_hps_in_write <= 1'b1 ; //write flag
        FPGA_to_HPS_state <= 4'd1 ;
    end
...
```

The compile report is telling there is a problem on the line
`mean <= c / 5;`

[image]

But the strange thing is when I change the line
`fpga_to_hps_in_writedata <= meaninput;`
to
`fpga_to_hps_in_writedata <= c;`
the problem disappear, the compile report about the timing didn't show the problem anymore.

`fpga_to_hps_in_writedata` will write the data of to the `FIFO` to send to `HPS`

Is this a problem on `FIFO` that something I need to change in `Qsys`?
I've read the recommendation but I've only learned about basic `Verilog` so no idea about the timing constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer division in combinatorial logic is very expensive in terms of both logic and time. You may want to find another way to get this result — perhaps there's a way to pipeline it, or use multiplication by 1/5.

Comment: You are right, after some research I found that the division seems like is the problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725657/division-in-verilog). I am now learning how to write a division module instead of using the operator `/` to see if the problem can be solved or not.

Comment: Hi Dave, do you mind if I ask again, I am having a square root module, originally it uses * operator to multiple, but I found that it is expensive too, so I modified it to <<, but I still got timing problem if I instantiate it to my FIFO, is it because I using the for loop? Because I need it to root 64 bits input, which needs to loop for 32 times. Is that might be the problem?

Comment: Yes, combinatorial square root has a similar level of complexity as divide.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Means the only way I can solve it is use clocked counter instead of for loop.